# Migration to tf.keras: lambdas how-to compile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

So I had next code in old keras-2.2 tf-1.13:

```
def RN_GlobalAveragePooling2D_r(f):
    def func(x):
        x    =  layers.multiply([x, f])
        repx =  int(x.shape[2])
        repy =  int(x.shape[3])
        x    = (backend.sum(x, axis=[2, 3], keepdims=True) / (backend.sum(f, axis=[2, 3], keepdims=True)))
        x    =  backend.repeat_elements(x, repx, axis = 2)
        x    =  backend.repeat_elements(x, repy, axis = 3)    
        return x
    return Lambda(func)
```

And called it like so: `s_1  = RN_GlobalAveragePooling2D_r(S_mask)(DOG1)`

now I want to migrate to tf-2.2, yet I  get a compile error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Train_DOGLSTM.py", line 24, in <module>
    model = M.my_model(encoder = encoder, input_size = (options.img_h, options.img_w, 3), k_shot = options.kshot, learning_rate = options.learning_rate)
  File "/content/drive/MyDrive/sc/model.py", line 178, in my_model
    s_1  = RN_GlobalAveragePooling2D_r(S_mask)(DOG1)   
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 954, in __call__
    input_list)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 1093, in _functional_construction_call
    inputs, input_masks, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 824, in _keras_tensor_symbolic_call
    return self._infer_output_signature(inputs, args, kwargs, input_masks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 871, in _infer_output_signature
    keras_tensor.keras_tensor_from_tensor, outputs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 810, in map_structure
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/util/nest.py", line 810, in <listcomp>
    structure[0], [func(*x) for x in entries],
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/keras_tensor.py", line 606, in keras_tensor_from_tensor
    out = keras_tensor_cls.from_tensor(tensor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/keras_tensor.py", line 205, in from_tensor
    type_spec = type_spec_module.type_spec_from_value(tensor)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/type_spec.py", line 564, in type_spec_from_value
    (value, type(value).__name__))
TypeError: Could not build a TypeSpec for <KerasTensor: shape=(None, 5, 7, 7, 128) dtype=float16 (created by layer 'tf.concat_1')> with type KerasTensor
```

So how one writes [lambdas](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda?version=nightly) that take two arguments like shown here for TF.keras in 2.x?

Comment: I tried your code on colab with random inputs and did not get an error, can you please add some code such that the error can be reproduced?

Comment: Are you asking if you want result in float16? If so, yes, you have to pass dtype=tf.float16 to layers as a parameter. and github code is not advisable, keep the code as minimum as possible (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)